# How to plot a subset of plot_model x-axis items in ggplot2 without filtering data before plotting?

Tags: r, ggplot2, sjplot

I would like to use `sjPlot::plot_model` to generate some marginal effects plots that are later modified slightly. Specifically, I would like to run a regression with an ordered categorical predictor. I would then like to run `plot_model` on the regression object to generate a `ggplot2` object but drop some elements of the categorical predictor for ease of visualization (for example, from 10 categories in the regression to 5 categories in the plot).

I know I can use `ggeffects::ggpredict()` to generate the underlying data used by `plot_model` but was hoping there was something simpler like passing an argument to `scale_x_discrete()`.

This is the standard `plot_model` output. Is there a straightforward way to drop one of the x-axis elements like "6" but still plot "4" and "8"?

[image: marginal effects plot of automatic transmission vs number of cylinders]

```
library(sjPlot)

mt <- mtcars

mt$cyl_fct <- as.factor(mt$cyl)

# automatic transmission vs number of cylinders
glm_out <- glm(am ~ cyl_fct, family = binomial, data = mt)

# plot model works fine but how to just show just 4 and 8 on x-axis?
plot_model(glm_out, type = "eff", terms = "cyl_fct") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 0.1)) 

# options like `breaks` and `limits` don't seem to do the trick
plot_model(glm_out, type = "eff", terms = "cyl_fct") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 0.1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("4", "8"), limits = c("4", "8"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the terms that you want to plot in the plot_model function, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sjPlot)

mt <- mtcars
mt$cyl_fct <- as.factor(mt$cyl)

# automatic transmission vs number of cylinders
glm_out <- glm(am ~ cyl_fct, family = binomial, data = mt)

# plot model works fine but how to just show just 4 and 8 on x-axis?
plot_model(glm_out, type = "eff", terms = "cyl_fct[4, 8]") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 0.1))
#> Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', which will
#> replace the existing scale.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

--
If this looks a little weird due to the "gap" where a term is supposed to be, you can then adjust the x axis scale to suit, e.g.

```
plot_model(glm_out, type = "eff", terms = "cyl_fct[4, 8]") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 0.1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c(4, 8), limits = c(4, 8))
```

[image: example_2.png]

Comment: Thank you. What's funny is I've done this 100 times but got so focused on adjusting the x-axis via scale_x_discrete that I simply forgot about using brackets in plot_model. Gracias!